# Can Infinispan act as a replacement for a conventional RDBMS

Tags: infinispan, key-value-store

Apologies if the title made no absolute sense. But, on the other hand, I would like to know if there is any programming model which would let us use Infinispan cache as a real datastore and not just a grid on top of an underlying rdbms.

I know Key-Value stores have real limitations but I couldn't stop thinking about the possibilities of an in-memory solution with all or a subset of RDBMS functionalities. For example: If I want to retrieve a particular set of Keys based on value>34.56%, just like how we would use a where clause in an sql stmt.

My doubt is not specific to infinispan but any IMKVS for that purpose. I know it's a shot in the dark considering the data structures and algorithms behind IMKVS specifications.

Any help or direction to resources which talk about these lines would be of great help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you write down all the queries that you execute against SQL DB and check if these could be translated into KVS language.

In Infinispan you can index the values and execute queries for such filtering, but you can't do any table joins.

If you are in need for more powerful API, specifically using JPA, take a look at [Hibernate OGM](http://hibernate.org/ogm/).

And while KVSs offer some level of reliability, in practice I wouldn't trust the documentation too much. You need to perform extensive testing of your system and check that you can retrieve the data even after various types of crashes and network failures (or that you can live with throwing the data away).

Comment: Hibernate OGM provides a much sophisticated JPA to deal with various datasources.@Flavius, thanks for the quickk turnaround. Appreciate that :)